# Cannot connect to database over VPN - keeps timing out

Tags: database, networking, vpn, connection-timeout, amazon-aurora

I am trying to connect to an Aurora MySQL database through a VPN connection. VPN credentials seem to work fine, as I can ping the host without any packet loss. However, when attempting to connect to the database, it simply times out. I have tried different SQL database softwares, but the issue keeps happening.

After troubleshooting with my colleagues, we arrived to the conclusion that the issue relies purely on my connection. My network provider suggested that it could be the fact that I have an IPv6 connection (and I'm trying to connect to an IPv4), but wouldn't in that case the VPN wouldn't be working either?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. I'm no expert in networking, so apologies if this is a rather basic question, but I haven't found anything useful for my case up to now.

I'm using:

- MacBook Pro High Sierra 10.13.6
- Tunnelblick VPN
- Sequel Pro and RazorSQL as database software (could use any other
  that works on OSX though)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder if your sql client is somehow binding itself to your underlying local ip address rather than your vpn one? Maybe the sql connection has an option to specify the local ip address.

Comment: Another possibility, your VPN might not allow all ports to go through.  Try a direct `telnet <DB SERVER IP> <MySQL port>` to see if you can connect at the network level.  If that does not work, it has to do with network.  If it does, your problem with MySQL connection (client, parameter error, user permissions, ...).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I haven't found any option to specify the local IP address on the SQL softwares. @Nic3500 I tried the telnet command and got the following response:
Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to XX.XX.XX.XX.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
5.6.10�w)eBZ|&A�Te!p3Ld1g3f,mysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Ok so you know you have network access (i.e. no firewall blocking it, routes exist, ...).  So since you have that, you now know that it is at the MySQL level.  Either you do not use the proper driver, or your username-password is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue in Mac M1 with tunnelblick vpn and faced connection problem with Mysql work bench. Initially I can able to connect DB with out any issue but after some time facing the connectivity issues even giving the accurate credentials and Db details. After spent lot time I got to know that there is something wrong with Openvpn and this Mysql work bench, so I started some changes in vpn settings. At last I found an solution by unchecking the Disable IPV6 unless the vpn server is accessed using IPV6(By default it was checked).You can find this option in vpn details and settings. It works for me.
Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).